# R in BERT won't use na.rm=TRUE in sum function

Tags: r, excel, bert-toolkit

I installed BERT (R-language to Excel interface). In the functions.R file that is included, i modified the included Add function to use the `na.rm` argument, as follows.

```
Add <- function( ... ) {
  sum(..., na.rm=TRUE);
}
```

However, it appears that the na.rm arugment is ignored.  That is, the Add() function works fine in Excel if all values in the range are present.
[that is =R.Add(A1:A5) in Excel works fine if all of cells A1:A5 contain values]
But if I delete any value in the range (so the Excel cell is blank), I get #NULL! returned.

Is it possible to utilize the na.rm argument, using BERT so that for R-language functions that have the na.rm argument, it is taken into account and blank cells within the Excel range still compute on the remaining values and do not return #NULL!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little complicated because the behavior is different if you are passing in one argument (a range) or multiple arguments (individual cells). But in the case of a single argument, if you pass in a range that has empty cells, this will be passed as a list. In that case, you will need to call `unlist`, e.g.

```
Add <- function( ... ) {
  sum(unlist(...), na.rm=TRUE);
}
```

Excel can have ranges that include different types (e.g. strings and numbers), but R can't. So when BERT passes data from Excel to R that has mixed types, it uses a list of lists.

There is a hint about this in the console when it runs, which is a good place to start -- it says that the argument is an invalid type (list).

As I said it's complicated because the three-dots argument could refer to multiple arguments, each of which could be a list or a single value (a scalar), each of which could be different types. In that case you'd need to use one of the `apply` functions to unlist different arguments. But try the above first.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this solves the issue. I mostly posed this question to try to learn from it, in general, how to handle na.rm. It sounds like the handling between R <-> Excel will differ based on the specific R function.